# Rounding(A+B) == Rounding(A) + Rounding(B)?

Tags: rounding-error, rounding-unit

Could I say 
    Rounding(A+B, n) == Rounding(A, n) + Rounding(B, n) ?

For example:

```
Rounding(23.56 + 76.44) = 100
Rounding(23.56, 0) + Rounding(76.44, 0) = 24 + 76 = 100
Rounding(23.56, 1) + Rounding(76.44, 1) = 23.6 + 76.4 = 100
Rounding(23.56, 2) + Rounding(76.44, 2) = 23.56 + 76.44 = 100
```

Comment: Your examples work because the rounding errors are of opposite sign and equal magnitude so they perfectly cancel. But they can instead amplify, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

In short, the answer is No.

Consider a counter-example:
Rounding(1.5,0)+Rounding(1.5,0)=2+2, which in not equal to Rounding (3,0).